# C# to T-SQL - Find Closest Weekday

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, datetime, linq-to-sql

Can any C#/T-SQL gurus help me out? I am having a difficult time trying to convert this C# code to T-SQL.

Here is the C# code:

```
        public (int distance, int absoluteDistance) MinimumDayOfWeekDistance(DayOfWeek dayOfWeekOne,
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeekTwo)
    {
        int forwardDaysDifference(int iteratorDayOfWeekOne, int iteratorDayOfWeekTwo) => iteratorDayOfWeekTwo -
                                                                                         iteratorDayOfWeekOne +
                                                                                         ((iteratorDayOfWeekOne >
                                                                                           iteratorDayOfWeekTwo)
                                                                                             ? 7
                                                                                             : 0);

        int forwardOneTwo = forwardDaysDifference((int) dayOfWeekOne, (int) dayOfWeekTwo);
        int forwardTwoOne = forwardDaysDifference((int) dayOfWeekTwo, (int) dayOfWeekOne);
        if (forwardOneTwo < forwardTwoOne)
        {
            return (forwardOneTwo, forwardOneTwo);
        }
        return (-forwardTwoOne, forwardTwoOne);
    }

    public int DaysToClosestDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeekOne, List<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeekList)
    {
        return dayOfWeekList.Select(dayOfWeek => MinimumDayOfWeekDistance(dayOfWeekOne, dayOfWeek))
            .Aggregate((x, y) => (x.absoluteDistance < y.absoluteDistance)
                ? x
                : ((x.absoluteDistance == y.absoluteDistance) ? ((x.distance > 0) ? x : y) : y)).distance;
    }
```

And here is the implementation:

```
int dayOfWeekDistance = this.DaysToClosestDayOfWeek(passedInDateParameter.DayOfWeek, myDayOfWeekList);
passedInDateParameter = passedInDateParameter.AddDays(dayOfWeekDistance);
```

The idea is that you have a list (a DayOfWeekList on the C# side), and that list can be filled with any day of the week. Could be Monday and Tuesday, Could be Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, and Saturday, etc.

There is a passed in DateTime parameter that is being compared to that list and is being updated according to which weekday it is closest to in the list.

For example, if the DateTime parameter being passed in is a Sunday, and my DayOfWeek list contains a Wednesday and Saturday, the parameter needs to be moved back to Saturday since it is closest in the list.

Similarly, if my list contains Sunday, Monday, and Saturday, and the parameter passed in is Thursday, then the parameter would have to be moved to Saturday.

Finally, if the parameter is equidistant from two week days in the list (Wednesday is passed in and Monday and Friday are in the list... or Sunday is passed in and Tuesday and Friday are in the list), then the parameter needs to be moved forward to the next closest week day (which, in the first case, would be Friday, and Tuesday in the second case).

So far on the SQL side, I have a VARCHAR variable representing a list of numbers based on each weekday. For example, the variable would be something like "126" if Sunday, Monday, and Friday were supposed to be contained within the variable.

Furthermore, on the SQL side, it would be optimal to return the minimum distance of the input parameter from the closest weekday in the list.

For example, if I pass in a Thursday (or a 5 for how it is currently implemented), and Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday, are in the list (or 1,2, and 3), a -2 should be returned (since Tuesday is closest to Thursday in the list), that way I can subtract 2 days from my target datetime variable (the datetime variable is outside the scope of this question, just here for reference purposes).

Put simply, distances of the input parameter from the closest day of the week should be returned, and they can be positive or negative in order to effectively account for the amount of days that should be added or subtracted.

So far the implementation works great in C#, I am just having a hard time converting it over to SQL because it is not my best language.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is Sunday closer to Thursday than Saturday is?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am confused as to what you mean. Are you referring to the second example I provided when talking about the DayOfWeek list?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer for you. First things first, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb635/1/0)

Here's the SQL:

```
create table test_Table (Days int);

declare @DaysList int
declare @x int
declare @Day int

set @DaysList =  36 
/*This is the variable that you mention in your original question. 
For example, 36 means Tuesday and Friday*/

set @Day = 1 
/*This is the day that you're checking against*/

set @x = 1
/*This is just our while loop variable*/

WHILE @x <= len(@DaysList)
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO test_Table
    SELECT substring(cast(@DaysList as nvarchar(7)),@x,1)
    SET @X = @X + 1 
  END 
/*The while loop is taking each digit in your @DaysList variable 
and putting it in its own row. 
This makes it so that we can compare our day to each day in the list
more easily.*/

;with cte as (SELECT case when abs(@Day-days) < 7-abs(@Day-days)
            then abs(@Day-days) 
            else 7-abs(@Day-days) end daysDiff
/*This field finds the number of days between the @Day value and the day
from @DaysList that we're comparing to. Basically, the smaller the number 
the better.*/
, days
/*This value is going to be the result of our query*/
, case when days-@Day between 0 and 8 
   then days-@Day
   when days+7-@day between 0 and 8
   then days+7-@Day 
   else -100 end a
/*This is doing a bunch of stuff to meet the requirement of finding the "next day" 
if the day is in the next week (for example, if @DaysList is Friday and Sunday (6 and 1)
and our @Day is Saturday (7), we want to show 1, not 6.*/ 
FROM #test_Table)

SELECT TOP 1 days FROM cte ORDER BY DaysDiff Asc, a
/*this just gives us our final result.*/
```

If you prefer to have this as a SQL function, you could create the function:

```
create function ClosestDayToDate(@Day int, @DaysList int)
RETURNS int AS BEGIN 

declare @x int
declare @result int
declare @test_table table (days int)
set @x = 1 

WHILE @x <= len(@DaysList)
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @test_Table
    SELECT substring(cast(@DaysList as nvarchar(7)),@x,1)
    SET @X = @X + 1 
  END 

;with cte as (SELECT case when abs(@Day-days) < 7-abs(@Day-days)
            then abs(@Day-days) 
            else 7-abs(@Day-days) end daysDiff
, days
, case when days-@Day between 0 and 8 
   then days-@Day
   when days+7-@day between 0 and 8
   then days+7-@Day 
   else -100 end a
FROM @test_Table)

Select @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 days FROM cte ORDER BY DaysDiff Asc, a)

return @result
END
```

Then, you could run the function:

```
SELECT dbo.ClosestDayToDate(1,72)
```

Which would return `2`.

If you need more clarification on anything, please let me know.

EDIT: I'm still really entranced by this function, so I keep on editing it to make it shorter. I think that this is the shortest I can get without completely re-working how it's written, though:

```
create function ClosestDayToDate(@Day int, @DaysList int)
RETURNS int AS BEGIN 

declare @x int
declare @result int
declare @test_table table (days int)
set @x = 1 

WHILE @x <= len(@DaysList)
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @test_Table
    SELECT substring(cast(@DaysList as nvarchar(7)),@x,1)
    SET @X = @X + 1 
  END 

;with cte as (SELECT days
, case when days-@Day between 0 and 8 
       then days-@Day
       when days+7-@day between 0 and 8
       then days+7-@Day 
       end a

FROM @test_Table)

Select @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 days FROM cte ORDER BY a)

return @result
END
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a74f2/8/0) for the function.

Edit: Per your request, I've updated the function. Now it will show the number of days between the "day" put in, and the nearest day from the "day list." If the day is prior to, it will show a negative number.

FYI--I have not tested this as exhaustively as I did the previous versions, but in the tests that I did, it worked alright.

```
create function ClosestDayToDate(@Day int, @DaysList int)
RETURNS int AS BEGIN 

declare @x int
declare @result int
declare @test_table table (days int)
set @x = 1 

WHILE @x <= len(@DaysList)
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @test_Table
    SELECT substring(cast(@DaysList as nvarchar(7)),@x,1)
    SET @X = @X + 1 
  END 

;with cte as (SELECT days
, case when abs(days-@Day) < days+7-@Day then days-@Day else days+7-@Day end b
, case when abs(days-@Day) < days+7-@Day then abs(days-@Day) else days+7-@Day end c         
FROM @test_Table)

Select @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 b FROM cte ORDER BY c, b desc)

return @result
END
```

And the [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05068/3)

Comment: Nice! This worked nicely! I just have one question. Is it possible to return a negative day? For example, if the date parameter passed in was a Wednesday, and Tuesday and Saturday were in the list, Tuesday is the closest day so would it be possible to return a -1 as the return value in the function? That way I can appropriately account for adding days to a DateTime Variable. Such as: SET DateTimeVar = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(dd, SomeVar, SomeOtherVar)). That way the date can effectively traverse backwards and forwards. Does that make sense? Otherwise it is perfect!!

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an error on my part. Your first solution worked logically, but I was unclear on what I wanted to be outputted. Is it possible to return the minimum DISTANCE from the input day and the days in the list? For example, if I input SELECT dbo.ClosestDayToDate(1,57), since Saturday (7) is closest to Sunday (1), it would be optimal to return -1, that way I can subtract 1 day from my datetime variable and move it back to it's proper date. Similarly, keeping the equidistant priority rule in mind, (1,36) should return 2 (Sunday is between Tuesday and Friday)... (4,257)=1, (4,12)=-2..

Comment: Does that make sense? Please don't hesitate to let me know if you need any clarification.